# Do I get notified if any comments in answer for my question

Tags: support, comments, notifications

First I'm not sure whether there is a feature like this

**Do I get notified for any comments from third person for an answer in my question?**

- When  Paritosh commented the answer posted by kart (25mins), for this
  **I didn't get notification.**

[image]

**- I haven't received any notification for Paritosh's comments**

[image]

- This is comment posted by John for which I got last notification (an
  hour before)

[image]

Just want to let you know about this behavior is this working as expected?

Answer (score 4):

It's working as expected.  You get an inbox notification for comments on your question, or for any comments with an @ reply to you, but not for comments to answers within your question.

Comment: But it should have notified me right, if you read the comment the third person commented pointing me based on the answer.

Comment: @user1671639 No, they did not specifically reply to your comment using the site's reply functionality, as I am doing now, which is why you didn't get a notification.  If they did prefix their post with @ followed by your name, you would have been notified.

Comment: I agree however that the site should - you are engaged in a thread of comments, the reply is more than likely to be of some interest to you. @user1671639

Comment: @Chris and if a comment thread on an answer gets hijacked by unrelated discussion (maybe a back-and-forth debating an insignificant piece of the answer), you will annoy users with too many pings.  I'd rather be notified of edits to answers than comments on answers

Comment: @psubsee2003 Perhaps a Facebook-esque 'unfollow' would also be useful.